# How to use angular select with objects

Tags: angular, select

I'm getting roles from rest-api in my component like:

```
this.userService.getRoles().subscribe(data => this.roles = data);
```

Then I'm trying to use it in my template as below:

```
<select name="role" [(ngModel)]="user.role">
    <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [ngValue]="role">{{role.name}}</option>
</select>
```

But it's not working, output for {{roles | json}}, so everything is fine with them, the problem is select doesn't work.

```
[{"id":1, "name":"user"}, {"id":2, "name":"admin"}]
```

Comment: any errors in the console

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka ERROR TypeError: "_co.user is undefined"

Comment: define the user object on your component `user = { role: 'user'}`

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka user is defined as well, output for {{user | json}} is { "id": 1, "login": "admin", "password": "admin", "email": "admin@admin.com", "firstName": "Admin", "lastName": "Johnson", "birthday": "1995-06-06", "role": { "id": 2, "name": "admin" } }

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka it doesn't work even without ngModel directive, I've tried everything. Is anything need to be imported for using angular select?

Comment: hmm seems suspicious. can u create a demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[compareWith]`. [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvmd7n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="selected" [compareWith]="compare">
      <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [ngValue]="role">{{ role.desc }}</option>
    </select><br>
    <p>Selected role : {{ selected | json }}</p>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  roles = [
    {id: 1, desc: 'Admin' },
    {id: 2, desc: 'User' },
  ];

  selected: any;

  compare(obj1, obj2) {
    return obj1 && obj2 && obj1.id === obj2.id;
  }
}
```